# thinkster MEAN stack tutorial - ui router and inline template

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am working on thinkster 'Learn to Build Modern Web Apps with MEAN' tutorial. The tutorial worked well till the ui-router part. After coding the ui-router and using the inline template, my index.html is blank. googled quite a bit but I am not able to find anything helpful. Here's my code.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flapper News</title>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="flapperNews">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
        {{post.upvotes}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
          <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
          </a>
          <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <form ng-submit="addPost()"
        style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Title"
            ng-model="title"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Link"
          ng-model="link"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', []);


app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home/',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })

    .state('posts', {
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: '/posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);


app.factory('posts', [function(){
  var o = {
    posts: []
  };
  return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
function($scope, posts){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';

  $scope.posts = posts.posts;

  $scope.addPost = function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
    $scope.posts.push({
      title: $scope.title,
      link: $scope.link,
      upvotes: 0,
      comments: [
        {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
        {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
      ]
    });
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.link = '';
  };

  $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
    post.upvotes += 1;
  };

}]);

app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$stateParams',
  'posts',
  function($scope, $stateParams, posts){

}]);
```

Comment: That additional "/" can make a difference. Did you try this as your url ? http://[hostname]/[root-dir]/#/home/